# How can I re-render the component in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to develop a note diary. When I add something, everything should appear in the correct order. The sortOrder function should be working. My note (list) is sorted. I let that show up me in the console.

But the notes are not displayed sorted. I want to add an Note by paste it sorted in the useEffect hook method, which is in UserForm.js data. NoteContainer should be overridden in a sorted order. How can I do that?

```
// UserForm.js

import Input from '../Input/Input'
import TextArea from '../TextArea/TextArea'
import Button from '../Button/Button'
import './UserForm.css'

import NoteContext from '../../Context/NoteContext'
import { useRef, useContext, useEffect } from 'react'

const listOrder = (a, b) => {

  if (a.date.getDate() > b.date.getDate())
  {
    return 1;      
  }
  
  else if (a.date.getDate() < b.date.getDate())
  {
    return -1;
  }
  
  else{
    return 0;
  } 
}

export default function UserForm() {

  const {notes, setNotes} = useContext(NoteContext);

  const titleRef = useRef("");
  const dateRef = useRef("");
  const textRef = useRef("");

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    const neueList = [...notes];
    // const options = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' };

    neueList.push({
      id: Date.now(),
      title: titleRef.current.value,
      date: new Date(dateRef.current.value),
      text: textRef.current.value
    });

    setNotes(neueList);
  
    console.log(notes);
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(notes.length > 1){
      notes.sort(listOrder);
    }
  },[notes]);

  return (
    <form className='form-container' method='get'>
        
        <div className='inputs form-flex-container'>
            <Input ref={titleRef}  label="Titel" type="text" placeholder="Titel der Notiz" name="titel" form="form-container" />
            <Input ref={dateRef} label="Datum" type="date" placeholder="tt.mm.jjjj" name="datum" form="form-container"/>
            <Button form="form-container" inhalt="Notiz hinzufügen" onClick={() => submitHandler(Event)}/>
        </div>

        <div className='text-areas form-flex-container'>
            <TextArea ref={textRef} label="Inhalt der Notiz" placeholder="Deine Notiz ..." name="notiz-text" form="form-container"/>
        </div>

    </form>
  )
}
```

```
// App.js

import Header from "./Components/Header/Header";
import NoteContainer from "./Components/NoteContainer/NoteContainer";
import NoteContext from "./Context/NoteContext";

import { Fragment, React, useState } from 'react';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

export default function App() {

  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <NoteContext.Provider value={{notes, setNotes}}>
        <div className="MainContainer">
          <Header />
          <NoteContainer />
        </div>
      </NoteContext.Provider>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

```
// NoteContainer.js

import React from 'react'
import NoteItem from '../NoteItem/NoteItem'
import './NoteContainer.css'

import { useContext } from 'react'
import NoteContext from '../../Context/NoteContext'

export default function NoteContainer() {

    const {notes} = useContext(NoteContext);

  return (
    <div className='NoteContainer'>
        {notes.map((note)=>{
            return <NoteItem date={note.date.toLocaleDateString("de-DE")} title={note.title} key={"key-" + note.title + "-" + note.id} />
        })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Effects happen _after_ rendering, because it's side-effect code that has nothing to do with the component itself, sort your notes as part of the note saving event handler `submitHandler` (take your preexisting notes list, add the new note, sort the list, then setState that new list), don't use an effect.